# How can I add two numbers from a char in C?

Tags: c, char, int, pipe, fifo

I'm using two files one that is sending and the other is receiving a char using pipes and it's working fine but I want to know how after I receive the message I want to convert that char in integers and add or subtract based on what is on the char.

Basically how can I parse "3+4" into 7?

Here is my write.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
int fd;
char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

/* crear FIFO  */
mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

/* escribir al FIFO */
fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "3+4", sizeof("3+4"));
close(fd);

/* remover FIFO */
unlink(myfifo);

return 0;
}
```

And this is my read.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
int fd;
char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
char buf[MAX_BUF];

/* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
close(fd);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's not really woring fine as long as you call`write(fd, "3+4", sizeof("3+4"));` instead of `write( ...., strlen( "3+4" ) );`

Comment: Please format/indent your code.

Comment: and show us what yu have tries so far to parse the message you have received

Comment: Elaborate your question. It's not clear what you want, maybe [`atol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) is what you need ?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt, on the contrary, using `sizeof()` in that case has the advantage of including the space for the null terminator in the count, which may (sometimes) be exactly what is wanted.  In particular, note that string literals represent *arrays*, not pointers, so `sizeof()` does report on the number of elements.  It should not be problematic here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're right of course. Nevertheless I somehow suspect that when the constant was replaced by an array or a pointer, the sizeof would stlill be there

Comment: The reading and wring of the string from/to the file appears to have nothing to do with OP's goal which is effectively: How to parse `"3+4"` into `7`.

Comment: @Dictatorboy, you seem to be asking how to parse the input as an expression, and then to evaluate the resulting expression.  Such a question is far too broad for SO.  If you meant to ask something more specific, then this would be a good time to edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

if this is just about adding 2 numbers (ass opposed to a general purpose calculator) why not just send "3,4"

Now split the string at the ",". Hint - use strchr

Now convert the two substrings to integers. Hint use atol

Now add them. Hint use `+`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the string to get the arithmetic expressions. As the commenters already said: such a question is a bit too broad here because there are a lot of ways to do so, depending on how complex the expressions can get. For a simple addition/subtraction of two positive integers--not more than `s1 + s2` or `s1 - s2`, no negations or anything else--you can use this *very* simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

#define ADD 1
#define SUB 2

int parse(char *s)
{
  int op1 = 0, op2 = 0, res = 0, operator= 0, next = 0;
  for (;;) {
    switch (*s) {
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
        // may over/underflow, check!
        if (next == 0) {
          op1 *= 10;
          op1 += *s - '0';
        } else if (next == 1) {
          op2 *= 10;
          op2 += *s - '0';
        }
        break;
      case '+':
        operator = ADD;
        next = 1;
        break;
      case '-':
        operator = SUB;
        next = 1;
        break;
      case '\0':
        // may over/underflow, check!
        if (operator == ADD) {
          res = op1 + op2;
        } else if (operator == SUB) {
          res = op1 - op2;
        }
        break;
      default:
        // just ignore everything else for now
        break;
    }
    if(*s == '\0'){
      break;
    }
    s++;
  }
  return res;
}

int main()
{
  char *s = "3 + 4";
  printf("%s = %d\n",s, parse(s));
  s = "3 - 4";
  printf("%s = %d\n",s, parse(s));
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And although it *is* very simple and of not much use it is already quite complex. You can extend it--to some extend--but you'll reach a limit quite quickly.

If you have nothing more than a line of arithmetic operations you might take some time to look up things like e.g.: "parse infix expressions" or similar here and elsewhere. The first hit at Google is the Wikipedia page about the [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) which should give you a good start. It is quite interesting stuff but nothing for just half an evening to learn.